# Problem in the installation of R packages on SageMaker

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, terra

I cannot install the R package terra on SageMaker. Can anyone help me please?

This is supposed to work, but does not:

`install. Packages("terra", repo="https://cran.rstudio.com/")`

`library("terra")`

Give the following error

````
“installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status”
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'

Making 'packages.html' ...
 done

Error in library("terra"): there is no package called ‘terra’```
````

Comment: The function install.packages is returning non-zero exit status, this means that the installation is ending unsuccessfully.

¿Are you using SageMaker RStudio? It could be that the Studio instances are launched on private VPC without Internet access.

Maybe trying to activate the verbose option (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/install.packages) we get some more details about the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first install the system requirements for terra. See instructions [here](https://github.com/rspatial/terra)

Comment: Thanks Robert! Do you mean to install gdal and proj?